# Toggle warnings with fsyntax-only parameter

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, g++

I have a question concerning compilation between g++ and gcc.

If I write this code:

```
int main(int args, char* argv[]){
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it with: `g++ -fsyntax-only -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

whether the file has a `.c` or a `.cpp` extension it won't complain about unused paramaters(`args` and `argv`).

The `-Wunused` option will only work if I compile the file with a `.c` extension and `gcc`.

So my question is: is it possible to enable warnings with `fsyntax-only` parameter in all other cases ?

Thank you in advance for any reponse

Comment: No, it is not, -fsyntax-only only checks the syntax.

Comment: @nos That should be posted as an answer, not as a comment. It would then likely be downvoted for being incorrect, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, -fsyntax-only only checks the syntax. – nos

[**Options to Request or Suppress Warnings**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options):

> `-fsyntax-only`
>
> Check the code for syntax
>   errors, but don’t do anything beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

This anomaly appears to have been a g++ compiler bug. The OP's
observations are confirmed with g++ 5.4 but g++ 6.3 gives
the expect warnings:

```
$ g++-6 -fsyntax-only -Wall -Wextra -Werror test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:1:14: error: unused parameter ‘args’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 int main(int args, char* argv[]){
              ^~~~
test.cpp:1:31: error: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]
 int main(int args, char* argv[]){
                               ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```